# execute a cronjob exactly once

Tags: php, mysql

I have a cronjob that loops through and updates a MySQL table row by row. After the table is 'completed', I would like to execute the cronjob exactly 1 more time, to perform various cleanup activities. Is there a way to store a piece of metadata in the MySQL table so that I can set a value to test for on subsequent cron loops to force an exit?

Right now I have:

```
if (count($records)==0) {  // table completed
    $result = $this->mlist_model->updatelist();  // EXECUTE EXACTLY ONCE

    // SET SOME SORT OF FLAG HERE TO TEST FOR AND EXIT
    exit;
}
```

Comment: You could just do the chron job once per whatever. Have a function "doing the loop" and just call that function twice in the job?

Comment: It's best to set that value in the mysql database, e.g. `needs_cleanup = 1`. That way you can always find those records at a later time. Keeping it in the database allows to to recover, for example, if a cron-job wasn't executed or failed half-way the loop.

Comment: My thought exactly, But where in the DB or table would you put flag cleanup=1?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the [at](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at) command

Comment: Thanks Ed, I looked at the at Man page you provided. If I understand correctly this executes a cron job at a specific time. However I can't be sure of the exact time that the extra single cron job should run, so unless I am misunderstanding I don't think that will work

Comment: "I would like to execute the cronjob exactly 1 more time" - at will fire off the task just the once. Do not need the check as it has been just the once as required.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @RomanC - The objective is to execute a task once to preform "various cleanup activities". Therefore my proposed solution fulfills this requirement.

Comment: I am sure that the person is able to look up the `at` command. Just put the link in for the persons benefit.

Comment: Ed , I looked at the man page again. Unless I'm missing something you have to specific time for at. I need a logical command for this solution. Regards - Bill

Comment: You can do `at now` or `at now+summat` to run the command to do the tidy up in the future.