# Can a mysql table contain a table specific metadata flag

Tags: mysql

I have a cronjob that loops through and updates a MySQL table row by row. After the table is 'completed', I would like to execute the cronjob exactly 1 more time, to perform various cleanup activities.

In [execute a cronjob exactly once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992102/execute-a-cronjob-exactly-once?noredirect=1#comment22801829_15992102), thaJeztah states:

> It's best to set that value in the mysql database, e.g. needs_cleanup = 1. That way you   can always find those records at a later time. Keeping it in the database allows to to recover, for example, if a cron-job wasn't executed or failed half-way the loop. – thaJeztah

I think this would be a good solution if its possible, as in my case I only need to set the flag once a day. If it is possible could someone point me to the sql commands nescesary to execute the placement of a simple binary flag, with values 0,1 in a mysql table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable SET needs_cleanup = 1
```

does it for all records of mytable. If you need for a single record, add a WHERE condition, e.g.

```
UPDATE mytable SET needs_cleanup = 1
WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without involving the records, but just the table?

Comment: The whole point of relational databases is to rely only on a single type of data structure, the table. If you start adding attributes to a table besides the fields, then it is no longer a table and you require other types of (non-relational) querying mechanisms. You could possibly change the comment property of a table but I think it's only recent versions of MariaDB that allow for it. Alternatively, you could have a table with table names and the field needs_cleanup to keep track of which tables need updating.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use your method